# what is proper route for admin folder in websites

Tags: laravel

Where should we keep the admin panel while developing our site using laravel or any frameworks of other language?

Is it like: 'www.mysite.com/admin'. Where should we keep the admin folder?

Currently I am using this trend 
'www.mysite.com/admin'

Is it good practice. If not please suggest me best and secure way.

Comment: ... "suggest"? Opinion based?

Answer (score 0):

Generally seprating admin or panel's routes, views and controllers is a good practise to keep every thing clean and considering [authentications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#introduction)

In my projects I even create a different route file in routes folder, though I have more controll of how my routes work

You control the access to admin's route via middlewares

The format of route is typically like`/admin`

Answer (score 0):

you can use any path for admin panel, just remember admin panel is supposed to be secure away from users or bots. do not let bots index it or users access it. my case is /admin and use a middleware to return 404 page if user isnt allowed to access admin panel.

example routes : /admin /cp /controlpanel

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function() { 
Route::get('/', 'Admin\HomeController@index')->name('admin_home');
});
```

all works, use the one that suits your need.

Extra: use a secret token on url and match it with your database or config files if you want a real private admin access. do not use this on commerical projects. its just for private safety on my end

Answer (score -1):

you can still put it on routes/web.php, just add middleware who can only see the admin side of your website/application.

For the directory, if you are using frameworks such as laravel, you don't need to separate the directory of the frontend and admin side of your website/application.